# How to get last date of current month, and next month when condition apply

Tags: javascript

I can get the current end of month date by below javascript. However, I get stuck on setting condition with it.
For instance, if the input date is after 21st of the current month, the lastDay will be the last day of next month.

```
var date = new Date();

var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various possiblities. For instance

```
var date = new Date();
var lastday;
if (date.getDate() > 21)
  lastday = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 2, 0);
else
  lastday = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
```

or using the ternary operator for assignment

```
var date = new Date();
var lastday = date.getDate() > 21 
  ? new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 2, 0)
  : new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
```

or calculating the monthOffset beforehand

```
var date = new Date();
var monthOffset = 1;
if (date.getDate() > 21) 
  monthOffset = 2;
var lastday =  new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + monthOffset, 0);
```

or calculating the monthOffset beforehand using a ternary operator

```
var date = new Date();
var monthOffset = date.getDate() > 21 ? 2: 1
var lastday =  new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + monthOffset, 0);
```

or calulating the monthOffset inline without additional variable

```
var date = new Date();
var lastday =  new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + (date.getDate() > 21 ? 2 : 1), 0);
```

They are all based on the same principle: Set the number of months to add to either `1` or `2`, based on the current date. For terms of readability, I would probably prefer the variant 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date();
var condition = date.getDate() > 21;
var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1 + (condition ? 1 : 0), 0);
```

If the current date is after the 21st, if will return the end of the next month, otherwise it will return the end of the current month.